# vector of intrinsics throws weird warning with g++ 7.2

Tags: c++, g++, intrinsics

A simple program throws a weird warning , the program tries to use vector of intel intrinsics. i am using g++ 7.2 , there is a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69884) in gcc which is resolved to be fixed but the warning still persists, i am not sure what are the implications to ignore the warning as intel intrinsics need strictly aligned data.

```
avx.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
avx.cpp:7:27: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘__m256i* {aka __vector(4) long long int*}’ [-Wignored-attributes]
     std::vector< __m256i* > v;
                           ^


#include <vector>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector< __m256i* > v;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The bug you link to shows that what was done to fix it, was to add a warning option `-Wignored-attributes` so that it'd become possible to disable the warning with `-Wno-ignored-attributes`. The warning message in your question shows that this is implemented in your compiler. As for an explanation of the warning, that also seems to be part of the bug report you link to already.

Comment: I thought at first it was warning about ignoring the alignment requirement of `__m256i`, but then I realized you have a vector of pointers to SIMD vectors.  Are you *sure* that's what you want?  If you're faking a 2D array, it's usually better to do the indexing manually rather than using an array or vector of pointers, unless you need that extra level of indirection to swap rows or something.